# Capture Maximized View Port Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way I can capture the view port width of a maximized browser window?

(the window obviously does not necessarily need to be maximized when reading in this value)

Answer (score 0):

screen.width will kind of get you there
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

but this is not fully accurate, but depending on your needs it may be good enough

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen size, `window.screen.availHeight` &&  `window.screen.availHeight` but this will not be the same as the inner dimensions of a maximized browser window `window.innerWidth` && `window.innerWidth`.